# Lazy loading bug in safari

Tags: javascript, lazy-loading

The lazy loading functionality is loading just fine on Chrome but for some reason on Safari it's not loading the images. Any help would be much appreciated.

here is the page: https://www.mrpaulxavier.com/test-success-page/

```
(this, this.document)); /*!Lazy Load 1.9.7 - MIT license - Copyright 2010-2015 Mika Tuupola*/
!function(a, b, c, d) {
  var e = a(b);
  a.fn.lazyload = function(f) {
    function g() {
      var b = 0;
      i.each(function() {
        var c = a(this);
        if (!j.skip_invisible || c.is(":visible"))
          if (a.abovethetop(this, j) || a.leftofbegin(this, j));
          else if (a.belowthefold(this, j) || a.rightoffold(this, j)) {
          if (++b > j.failure_limit) return !1
        } else c.trigger("appear"), b = 0
      })
    }
    var h, i = this,
      j = {
        threshold: 0,
        failure_limit: 0,
        event: "scroll",
        effect: "show",
        container: b,
        data_attribute: "original",
        skip_invisible: !1,
        appear: null,
        load: null,
        placeholder: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACxjwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsQAAA7EAZUrDhsAAAANSURBVBhXYzh8+PB/AAffA0nNPuCLAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC"
      };
    return f && (d !== f.failurelimit && (f.failure_limit = f.failurelimit, delete f.failurelimit), d !== f.effectspeed &&
```

thanks,
Manny

Comment: What you mean with lazy loading? What are you referring to?

Comment: What exactly is lazy loading? What element? How is it lazy loading? What's your code? Any error in the console? Please explain the problem in detail, don't just put a link and say "It doesn't work".

Comment: All the images on the website are not loading on scroll - I've given them a class of class="lazy"

In the console there is not issue that shows up for lazy loading so I'm not sure what exactly the issue is.

Comment: You added the plugin's minified source code :) Not sure this will be helpful. OK so, as I understand, all you're doing is adding the "lazy" class to images, and the plugin should then do its work. Any error in the console? The plugin should be tested for all browsers

Comment: From what it looks like there is an issue with the Opacity not toggling to 1

Comment: @MannyQuintanilla were you able get it to work on Safari?